# how to sum one column, multiply value of another and return object activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to find the top selling items. An Item has an `id` and `price`. It `has_many` ItemOrders, which `belongs_to` Item and has an `item_id`. I've tried...

```
Item.select('items.*, COUNT(item_orders.item_id) AS item_count')
.joins(:item_orders)
.group('items.id')
.order('SUM(item_count * items.price) DESC')
```

I'm not really seeing where the disconnect is here. I've done something similar before much more quickly. All I'm getting returned back, is the relation object. I''m trying to get an array of Item objects.

EDIT 
If I take out the multiplication it returns array of Items, but I don't think that's the top item since it's only a count of the records on the joins with that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've got it. I was over thinking as usual if this is right, lol.

```
def self.top_items(quantity=nil)
    Item.select('items.*, sum(item_orders.item_id * items.price) as sum')
      .joins(:item_orders)
      .group(:id)
      .order("sum desc")
      .limit(quantity)
  end
```

I *may* not need to count the `item_orders.item_id` before multiplying by the `items.price`